# SQL Server 2005 Reporting Services - Configuration Manager & Management Studio Problems

Tags: sql-server-2005, wmi, ssrs, ssms

When I open Reporting Services Configuration Manager on my server, an error message appears that says:

*Reporting Services Configuration Manager
An unknown error has occurred in the WMI Provider. Error Code 800706B3*

This error appears before I can even attempt to connect to an SSRS instance.

In addition to this problem, I'm not able to connect to my SSRS instance via SSMS on my desktop. When I attempt to connect, I get the following error message:

*Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio
Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. (mscorlib)
Additional information:
The operation could not be completed. (WinMgmt)*

**Information about my environment:**
Server: Win Server 2K3 x64, SQL 2005 x64 SP3 Build 9.0.4053
Desktop: Windows 7 Enterprise x64

**Steps I have already taken:**
I have installed the latest service pack on my server and workstation. I do not see any errors in my event logs.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you need to re-register the SSRS WMI Namespace and/or the WMI Provider. You can troubleshoot and fix the problem using the following steps.

**Troubleshoot the problem using the WMI Tester**

1. Close all instances of Reporting Services Configuration Manager or SQL Server Management Studio.
2. Open a command prompt and type wbemtest, and then click OK.
3. Click Connect in the WBEM tester dialog box
4. In the Namespace field, type the following string, and then click Connect. `root\microsoft\sqlserver\reportserver \v9`
5. The namespace you specify should appear in the WMI Tester dialog box. If you see an error message instead, the WMI namespace for Reporting Services is not registered correctly. To resolve this issue, follow the procedures later in this article for registering the WMI namespace for Reporting Services.
6. Click Enum Classes, and click OK in the Superclass Info window.
7. In Top-level classes list of the Query Result window, double-click the MSReportServer_Instance class.
8. Click the Instances button. You should see a Query Result window that shows all the instances of Report Server on your computer. If not, the Reporting Services WMI provider is not communicating with Reporting Services Configuration Manager or SQL Server Management Studio. To resolve this issue, follow the procedures later in this article for registering the Reporting Services WMI provider.
9. If you successfully resolved the issues in the WMI Tester dialog box, restart Reporting Services Configuration Manager or SQL Server Management Studio to determine whether that the error is resolved.

**Repairing Report Services WMI Provider**

1. Close all instances of Reporting Services Configuration Manager or SQL Server Management Studio.
2. Open a command prompt.
3. Add the class instance of the Reporting Services WMI provider to the WMI repository. In the command prompt, run the following command:
   `mofcomp "%ProgramFiles%\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Shared\reportingservices.mof"`
4. Run the WMI Tester again to see whether you can now connect to the namespace for the Reporting Services WMI provider and continue with the debugging process.

**Register the Reporting Services WMI provider**

1. Close all instances of Reporting Services Configuration Manager or SQL Server Management Studio.
2. Open a command prompt.
3. Register the Reporting Services WMI provider. In the command prompt, run the following command:
   `regsvr32 "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Shared\reportingserviceswmi.dll`
4. Run the WMI Tester again to see whether you can now connect to the namespace for the Reporting Services WMI provider and continue with the debugging process.

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd353297(SQL.90).aspx) is the source for this information, Microsoft's How-To on troubleshooting WMI Provider errors in SSRS.